# Skewing a background the opposite way round

Tags: css

I've never felt so silly asking a SO question... but here is goes.

I've created a skew which works a charm, see here

```css
.skewed-bg {
  background: #E7ADBB;
  padding: 200px 0;
  transform: skew(0deg, -7deg);
  margin-top: -200px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: white;
}

.skew-lb {
  padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.content {
  transform: skew(0deg, 7deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed-bg skew-lb">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 text-center">
          <h1 class="h1 hero-title mb-3">Everything you need to know about...</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I try to make the skew the opposite way round, everything just turns into mayhem and I have no idea why this is happening - surely it's just reversing the numbers of the skew around? This is my code...

```css
.skewed-bg {
    background: #E7ADBB;
    padding: 200px 0;
    transform: skew(-7deg, 0deg);
    margin-top: -200px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
}

.skew-lb {
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}
.content {
    transform: skew(7deg, 0deg);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed-bg skew-lb">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 text-center">
          <h1 class="h1 hero-title mb-3">Everything you need to know about...</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody put me out of my misery here? PS- I apologise in advance for being a plonker.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because **skew(ax, ay)**. If you simply reversed the angles, you would be changing **x-axis** instead of **y-axis**. So use an inverse angle instead. **7deg** becomes **-7deg**

Read about skew [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew).

Do it like this:

```css
.skewed-bg {
  background: #E7ADBB;
  padding: 200px 0;
  transform: skew(0deg, 7deg);
  margin-top: -200px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: white;
}

.skew-lb {
  padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.content {
  transform: skew(0deg, -7deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed-bg skew-lb">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 text-center">
          <h1 class="h1 hero-title mb-3">Everything you need to know about...</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can achieve the same result using `:before` selector. Less nesting.

```css
.container {
text-align: center;
height: 300px;
width:900px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
background: darkOrange;
height:100%;
width: 200%;
transform: rotate(15deg);
top: -35%;
left: -25%;
z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
z-index: 1;
color: white;
width: 100%;
line-height: 120px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<h1>Exmaple </h1>

</div>
```

- Using this method, the text will not be skewed

Answer (score -1):

change the -7 into a 7 in the skew
and for the content flip them over so ts like this `skew(0deg, -7deg)`

```css
.skewed-bg {
    background: #E7ADBB;
    padding: 200px 0;
    transform: skew(0deg, 7deg);
    margin-top: -200px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
}

.skew-lb {
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}
.content {
    transform: skew(0deg, -7deg);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed-bg skew-lb">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 text-center">
          <h1 class="h1 hero-title mb-3">Everything you need to know about...</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```